# KendoUI DropdownList - Removing autofocus from the filter text input

Tags: kendo-ui

With most tablets, if a text input has focus it will bring up the system keyboard. This is because the filter has focus. However, this is far from ideal, as the user typically wants to select from the dropdown, rather than type into the filter. I am trying to remove this behavior with jQuery:

```
open: function() {                        
  var input = this.filterInput;

  setTimeout(function() {                          
    input.blur();
  });
}
```

However, this keeps closing the list. I have created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZufGmhQMVPBn2WWIH0L).

Comment: It's closing automatically on click dropdown.